# Add a section of A URL to an already open Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm very new to jQuery and am looking for a way to append a section of a url to an already open window.

For example I have a link inside a div like this:

```
<script>
function addURL()
{
    $('#four').attr('href', function() {
        return this.href + '#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=4';
    });
}
</script>

<div class="size"> 
<a id="four" onclick="addURL();" href= “http://www.example.com/product/shoes”>  4 </a> </div>
```

I can make it so that each induvial link opens in a new window or replaces the old link e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/product/shoes'#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=4
```

Becomes

```
http://www.example.com/product/shoes'#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=5
```

What I cannot work out for the life of me is how to append the url to any other url that is currently open. For example:
`http://www.example.com/product/shoes'#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=4#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=5`....and so on and so forth.

Could anyone be kind enough to point us in the general right direction?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$('#four').attr('href', function() {
    return location.href + '#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=4';
});
```

Comment: So simple! Seems to of worked a treat. Thank you so much.